# Using Kong AWS Lambda plugin for request authentication

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, kong, kong-plugin

In Kong is it possible to reuse the AWS Lambda plugin to carry out authentication.

I have followed this documentation https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/aws-lambda/ for setting up the Lambda. I have a test AWS Lambda function that just returns the example response below.

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": {
        "response": "yes"
    }
}
```

Currently Kong just returns the Lambda response but is there a way that it can be used for the authentication? For example when requests come into Kong an AWS Lambda is called to figure out if the user is authenticated or not. If they are authenticated the request continues, if not a 401 response is returned.